# ¿ Cual es el limite óptimo de archivos que puede leer para Visual-Studio para no que no abuse de RAM?

Tags: ubuntu, archivo, vscode

Hola me encontré con el siguiente problema al abrir un proyecto en Visual-Studio:

***Visual Studio Code es incapaz de observar los cambios de los archivos en este espacio de trabajo tan grande. Por favor siga las instrucciones en el link para resolver este problema.***

Este es el link : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

Bien, ejecute el comando `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` y me da un resultado de 8192.
Dispongo de una memoria RAM de 8 Gb, teniendo en cuenta lo que consume Visual Studio, Google, etc.
Mi entorno es Ubuntu.
¿ Cual es limite óptimo para darle editando el archivo `/etc/sysctl.conf` ?
En la documentación indica como dar el máximo, pero 
¿ afectaría a la memoria darle el limite máximo, o solo afectaría al arranque de Visual Studio?

Gracias.

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta está basada en opiniones (dependerá de la RAM y el sistema que tengas), pero te comento que yo tengo ese mismo problema y lo solucioné siguiendo esa recomendación. También tengo 8GB de RAM y no he notado ningún problema en Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Gracias, seguiré esos pasos. Explica una respuesta y la doy por aceptada.